# Are there any differences between "from module.foo import bar" and "import module.foo.bar as bar"?

Tags: python, import

using the package layout [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

```
sound/                          Top-level package
      __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
      formats/                  Subpackage for file format conversions
              __init__.py
              wavread.py
              wavwrite.py
              aiffread.py
              aiffwrite.py
              auread.py
              auwrite.py
              ...
      effects/                  Subpackage for sound effects
              __init__.py
              echo.py
              surround.py
              reverse.py
              ...
      filters/                  Subpackage for filters
              __init__.py
              equalizer.py
              vocoder.py
              karaoke.py
              ...
```

it seems i can do both:

```
from sound.effects import echo
```

and

```
import sound.effects.echo as echo
```

what is the difference between these 2 syntaxes?

---

edit. a difference i have found is:

```
import sound.effects
del sound.effects
from sound.effects import echo              # ok
from sound.effects import echo as echo      # ok
import sound.effects.echo                   # ok
import sound.effects.echo as echo           # fail
```

this was tested on python 3.6; on python 3.7 all are ok;

Comment: `from sound.effects import echo, surround` <-- multiple imports in one line

Comment: @Eqomatic still doable: `import sound.effects.echo as echo, sound.effects.surround as surround`